# Fishpig Wordpress Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, fishpig

How to get category name and category Id of current blog category page in fishpig wordpress magento integration?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation? http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration/docs.html

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the current loaded category as follows:

```
<?php $category = Mage::registry('wordpress_category') ?>
<?php if ($category): ?>
    <?php echo $category->getId() ?>: <?php echo $category->getName() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```